# Netbeans: Is there a way to mimic Eclipse CTRL+H looking for usages in JRE and Application Libraries?

Tags: java, eclipse, search, netbeans

See Eclipse Java Search screenshot

[Eclipse Java Search http://giano.com.dist.unige.it/eclipseMirror/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.3-200706251500/whatsnew/images/search-dialog.png](http://giano.com.dist.unige.it/eclipseMirror/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.3-200706251500/whatsnew/images/search-dialog.png).

I googled a lot, tryied my best but could not find any ways to tell Netbeans to search for method invocation in JRE / Application libraries.

Let's consider:

- I have maven project with *ApplicationA* being runtime
- ApplicationA* artifat defines interface *InterfaceA* with method *methodA*
- I'm implementing the interfac as *InterfaceAImpl*

I'm looking for ways to find all the *InterfaceA#methodA* invocations in the *ApplicationA* (which is OpenSource and available) to see all the impacts and find all th usages.

Is this really possible only in Eclipse? I don't believe this.

Answer (score 2):

I usually rely on `Find Usages` in the `Edit` menu.

Comment: Thnx for response.
The thing is - I'm coming from Eclipse world and find "Find Usages" much more less powerful.

Comment: Indeed, there are fewer options, but it's easier to use, IMO. The options change to reflect the entity being sought, making selection quicker. I also use `Find in Projects`.

Comment: I understand that you are saying.

And this is my story(to be understood by other s too).

I have a project to plug-in into _projectA_, which is great but it's API / documentation isn't well enough documentated.
I need to implement some interface but I need to see there call tree, all the references to this component as well to see if I'm doing something wrong i couldsome things better they currently are.

In Eclipse I could use Ctrl+H and this is the end of the story. In Netbeans I will end up with adding all the 30 maven dependencies as projects and perform lookup only then. :(

Comment: I tried Netbeans and I liked that. But this is blocker or me to switch because I will end up with spending much more time finding the same information I gained access to so easy.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a member

```
private JMenuItem Edit
```

you can highlight the member name `Edit` and right click the context menu will have an option named "Find Usages" after selecting it a menu will open up and you can select where to search and the results will be displayed in an output window at the bottom.

I don't think it has as many search options as eclipse doe though.